# How to form a comparative adjective?

Tags: grammar, words, nouns

How to form a comparative adjective in Japanese (e.g. colder, warmer, deeper, higher)? Does it need to be compared to something?

Comment: Can you write an example sentence where a comparative adjective is used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use の方{ほう}が + adj for doing comparisons. It doesn't explicitly need another item to be compared to:

> これのほうが高いです
>   This one is more expensive

If you do need something to compare to, it can be used in conjunction with より:

> りんごのほうがオレンジよりおいしいです
>   Apples taste better than oranges

Or you can even leave のほうが out, like Yuuichi Tam's answer says, in order to imply the superior object and just state which object was inferior.

You also can use the adverb もっと to make an adjective comparative, but this just means "to a higher degree"; it's not used to compare to other things.

> もっと速く!
>   Faster!

Answer (score 2):

You can use より and it does usually need words to be compared to.

For example, 今日は、昨日より寒い (Today is colder than yesterday), あのビルは、このビルより高い (That building is higher than this building).

In addition you can say that without something to compare it to like より良い場所, it means " a nicer place than here" though.

Comment: So there's no way to say "a nicer place" without something to compare it to?

Comment: You can say "a nicer place" without something to compare it to like より良い場所, but it means " a nicer place than  here" though.